# Div largest height

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs

```
<div id="div1" style="float:left;">
</div>

<div id="div2" style="float:left;">
</div>

<div id="div3" style="float:left;">
</div>
```

In most of time div3 is the highest, I want div1 and div2 to have the same height as div3, is it possible to do?

Comment: give same `height` in `style` to all 3 divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [faux background](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) or the [holy grail technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail).

Alternatively, you could use a dash of JavaScript...

```
var divIds = ['div1', 'div2', 'div3'],
    divs = [],
    divsLength = divIds.length,
    maxHeight = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < divsLength; i++) {
   var div = document.getElementById(divIds[i]);
   maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, div.offsetHeight);
   divs.push(div);
}

for (var i = 0; i < divsLength; i++) {
   divs[i].style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ZLKFA/).